# mkdir permission denied vagrant

Tags: laravel, vagrant

Estoy usando windows 10 y vagrant. Cuando accedo a vagrant ssh quiero crear una carpeta dentro de Code, que es donde están todos mis proyectos.

Ahora, yo quiero crear un carpeta dentro de Code y me sale el error:

> [ErrorException] mkdir(): permission denied.

También le di permisos 777 pero sigo sin poder crear la carpeta.

Comment: Agrega más información, agrega como tratas de crear el directory y en que folder .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es `sudo mkdir carpeta`, o logeate como *root* *sudo su* y luego `mkdir carpeta`. No olvides salir del usuario *root* luego, simplemente con el comando *exit*.

Answer (score 0):

Verifica de quién es ese directorio dándole

```
ls -l
```

y si es de `root` entonces tenes que crearlas con

```
sudo mkdir nombrecarpeta
```